# GRASS r.reclass QGIS 2.14. error: "the following layers were not correctly generated"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, reclassify

I am getting a strange error message when running the GRASS r.reclass algorithm. 
The error states that:

"The following layers were not correctly generated
       *reclassified
 You can check the log message to find more information about the execution of the algorithm. "

After having read the log-file a couple of times, I am none the wiser.

All that I found were a couple of error messages...
"illegal latitude for north"
"Invalid input"
"Raster map not found"

If any of you have any idea what the reason is why the algorithm is not functioning correctly, please...let me know. 
See below for screenshots of log-file and re-class file. 
[image: r.reclass input parameters]

[image: r.reclass log file]

[image: reclass text file]

[image: error log after using NEW input parameters. still no succes]

New screen shots. I ran the r.reclass algorithm using different input parameters, but to no avail. (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax = -180,179,-64,90)

Answer (score 2):

The error report tell you that that you have entered illegal parameters. [image]

The values cant be over +/-180 for X and +/-90 for Y
In the tool box, try setting the xmin and ymax to -180 and 90 respectively.

Since the GRASS tool takes these attributes from the layers, it might hint that there might be an underlying error with the source layer's CRS or extents.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Sadly, it didn't work. I thought it couldn't be the x/y boundaries, because (like you said) these values are given by the layer itself. 
I entered new input parameters for xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax, but to no avail. See new screenshot I uploaded for details of error log

Comment: What are the extents of the original layer?

Comment: As seen in the first error log message:
-180.0013888888888971,-64.9986111111111171 179.9986111111111029,90.0013888888888829

Comment: I have no idea what the issue might be...? I think the only way to get the layer I want is to use a different reclass algorithm in QGIS. I saw there is a "SAGA - Reclassify Grid Values" algorithm. I'll try and see if this works

Comment: Ok...After having tried an extensive amount of different solutions, I have come to a very important conclusions:
Always make sure you load the graph you want to reclass, in it's own CRS and have the same CRS active in QGIS. 
In the reclass function, you have to enter the coordinates of the frame within which you want the reclass to take place. If you load the map in QGIS with a different CRS, it is indeed possible that you go out of bounds, and get an error message as I got.